# How to install opera-stable_26.0.1656.60_amd64.deb in centos6

Tags: opera, centos6, deb

I have downloaded opera-stable_26.0.1656.60_amd64.deb and searched how to install the same in my centos6.Got several links but none of them gave actual method.Please provide a suitable solution. I have tried with following command

yum install opera-stable_26.0.1656.60_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this script to convert the deb to an rpm:

http://ruario.ghost.io/2014/12/20/my-christmas-present-to-opera-fans-on-rpm-distros/